# Load JQuery after Kendo UI Scheduler done loading?

Tags: jquery, scheduler, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hej nerds :)

I have a page with to elements - a Dropdownlist and a kendoUI Scheduler. 
something like:

```
<div class="SchedulerHeader">
    <p> <label>Current View: </label>
      <select id"views">
        <option value="agenda">Agenda</option>
        <option value="day">Day</option>
        <option value="month">Month</option>
        <option value="week">Week</option>
        <option value="workWeek">Work Week</option>
     </select>
   </p>
</div>
 @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<myNameSpace.viewModel>().Name("myScheduler") #more options#

<script>
$(function() {

    var scheduler = $("#myScheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    $("#views").kendoDropDownList({
        value: scheduler.view(),
        change: function () {
            scheduler.view(this.value());
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My problem is that the js is load before the scheduler is done loading - which mean that my dropdownlist init value dosnt match the scheduler's view value. 
I can change the schedulers view by changing the value in the dropdownlist so the binding is ok. 
When I debug at pageload I see that the "value: scheduler.view()" is 'null'.

So my question is: how can I make sure that the js is loaded after the scheduler, without use of timers and without writing the scheduler in js ?

Merry Christimas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the answer.

My solution to my problem - was to Subscribe to the databound event of kendo UI scheduler. 
which look like this and set the value of the dropDownList to 'scheduler.view().name

```
<div class="SchedulerHeader">
<p> <label>Current View: </label>
  <select id"views">
    <option value="agenda">Agenda</option>
    <option value="day">Day</option>
    <option value="month">Month</option>
    <option value="week">Week</option>
    <option value="workWeek">Work Week</option>
 </select>
</p>
</div>
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<myNameSpace.viewModel>().Name("myScheduler") #more options#
 .Events(events => events.Databound("onLoad"))

<script>
 function onLoad(e){

var scheduler = $("#myScheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
$("#views").kendoDropDownList({
    value: scheduler.view()**.name**,
    change: function () {
        scheduler.view(this.value());
    }
});
})
</script>
```

Thanks for the answers
- Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1):

use callback:

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp

```
var scheduler = $("#myScheduler").data("kendoScheduler", function() {
    $("#views").kendoDropDownList({
        value: scheduler.view(),
        change: function () {
            scheduler.view(this.value());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Couldnt get it to work - if I build it like this, the event never fired. But your post did put me in the right path - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think RequireJS could be useful for you (http://requirejs.org/).

It allows you to define your JS files/plugins in a specific order and much more.
I let you have a look at it, hope it helps.